# UITableViewCell make only part of cell selectable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom TableViewCell and I would like that user can only tap/select the part of the cell in tableview.

I guess that this would be possible if I make the my CustomCell non selectable and then add UIButton inside my CustomCell on which the user can tap.

But are there any other ways of doing it?

Comment: Yes you are on the right way, there is no standard api to do it.

Comment: You could also just put a clear UIView over the non-selectable part.

Comment: What a selectable part you want?